# Is eternal life only for overcomers?

Tags: revelation

In Revelation 2:7 Jesus says:

> He who has an ear, let him hear what the Spirit says to the churches. To him who overcomes, I will grant to eat of the tree of life which is in the Paradise of God.

Is this verse saying that only overcomers are allowed to eat of the tree of life? What is the result of eating fruit from this tree, if not eternal life (for those who say John 3:16 means that everyone who believes in Christ obtains eternal life).

Additionally, Revelation 2:11 says:

> He who overcomes will not be hurt by the second death.

What is the "second death" and for those who *don't* overcome (but are still believers), what does the second death mean for them? Some commentaries say the second death is eternal hell, but that can't be the case for believers, can it?

Comment: How would you have turned out to be a true believer if you don't overcome? Wouldn't you have had a "lord lord" faith and not a real one?

Answer (score 5):

The operative verb in Rev 2:7 is νικάω (nikaó) which occurs about 28 times in the NT as variously (correctly) translated, overcome, conquer, overpower, prevails, be victorious, etc.

This passage about the reward to the Ephesian overcomers is one of a series of rewards which are unique to each of the seven churches.  Here is a more complete list:

**Ephesus:**

- right to eat from the tree of life in paradise

**Smyrna**

- crown of life
- not hurt by second death

**Pergamum**

- hidden manna
- white stone
- new name known only by receiver

**Thyatira**

- authority over nations
- morning star
- rule with iron sceptre
- dash nations to pieces like pottery

**Sardis**

- will walk with me
- dressed in white
- not erase name from book of life
- acknowledge before Father
- acknowledge before angels

**Philadelphia**

- pillar in God’s temple
- never leave temple
- write God’s name
- write name of God’s city
- write my new name
- kept from hour of trial

**Laodicea**

- right to sit with me [Jesus] on my [Jesus'] throne

Note that in each case, the rewards to each church are designed as the ideal rewards for the overcomers (and the difficulties & troubles) that each endured.

**ANNEX**

Now let me dispel a common misconception - there is (in some places) a theology that simply says that one is saved as soon as one "believes" based on texts like Rom 10:9, 10, Acts 16:31, 15:11, etc.  This is all very well but the Bible has much more than just this simplistic message about salvation.  Let us examine a number of other verses on this topic:

- “… but he that endures to the end shall be saved.”  Matt 10:22, 24:13, Mark 13:13.
- “We have come to share in Christ, if indeed we hold our original conviction firmly to the very end.” Heb 3:14
- “And we are his house, if indeed we hold firmly to our confidence and the hope in which we glory.” (Heb 3:6)
- “But now he has reconciled you by Christ’s physical body through death to present you holy in his sight, without blemish and free from accusation— if you continue in your faith, established and firm, and do not move from the hope held out in the gospel.” (Col 1:22, 23)
- “Blessed is the one who perseveres under trial because, having stood the test [= stood firm], that person will receive the crown of life that the Lord has promised to those who love him.” (James 1:12)
- “Therefore, my dear brothers and sisters, stand firm. Let nothing move you.” (1 Cor 15:58),
- “I have fought the good fight, I have finished the race, I have kept the faith.  Now there is in store for me the crown of righteousness, which the Lord, the righteous Judge, will award to me on that day …” (2 Tim 4:7, 8),
- “being strong in the Lord and in the strength of His might” (Eph 6:10)
- “So then, brothers and sisters, stand firm and hold fast to the teachings we passed on to you, whether by word of mouth or by letter.”  2 Thess 2:15
- "But the one who looks into the perfect law, the law of liberty, and perseveres, being no hearer who forgets but a doer who acts, he will be blessed in his doing.” (James 1:25)
- “Let us not become weary in doing good, for at the proper time we will reap a harvest if we do not give up.”  (Gal 6:9)

See also 2 Peter 1:5-7.  Note the key to understanding this idea as found in Eph 6:10 – “be strong in the Lord and in His might power”.  By ourselves we can do nothing (John 15:4, 5).  The keys to Christian perseverance are found in the great trio of virtues, “Faith, Hope and Love”.  1 Thess 1:3 and 5:8.  See also Eph 6:10-17 for a wonderful passage about Christian warfare.

The Bible has a wonderful promise for those that persevere in the faith: “My sheep listen to my voice; I know them, and they follow me.  I give them eternal life, and they shall never perish; no one will snatch them out of my hand.” John 10:27, 28.  Notice here and in all of the above that final salvation depends upon perseverance in the strength of the Lord NOT ours!

It is possible to see this question in another light.  The Bible makes it very plain that what we do (our "works") does not save us, but, the actions of saved saints may condemn us.  Notice the following:

- Luke 6:46, "Why do you call me, 'Lord, Lord,' and do not do what I say?”
- John 15:10, "If you love me, keep my commands.”
- James 2:18, “Show me your faith without deeds and I will show you my faith by my deeds.”
- Eph 2:10, “For we are God’s handiwork, created in Christ Jesus to do good works, which God prepared in advance for us to do.”
- Matt 5:16, “In the same way, let your light shine before others, that they may see your good deeds and glorify your Father in heaven.”
- 1 Thess 1:3, “We remember before our God and Father your work produced by faith, your labour prompted by love, and your endurance inspired by hope in our Lord Jesus Christ.”
- 2 Peter 1:5-7, “For this very reason, make every effort to add to your faith goodness; and to goodness, knowledge; and to knowledge, self-control; and to self-control, perseverance; and to perseverance, godliness; and to godliness, mutual affection; and to mutual affection, love.
- 2 Peter 3:11, 12, “…You ought to live holy and godly lives as you look forward to the day of God and speed its coming …”
- Gal 6:10, “…as we have opportunity, let us do good to all people …”
- Rev 12:17, describes the virtuous woman’s children as those “who keep the commandments of God and hold to the testimony of Jesus.”

Christian good works are part of the more general Christian duty of the Imitation of Christ.  An important part of the imitation of Christ is to grow to hate that which we once loved.  Thus, Christians grow to hate evil and all sin.

- Ps 36:1-3 – … for in his own eyes he flatters himself so much to detect or hate his sin.  Compare Rom 12:3
- Ps 97:10 – Those who love the Lord hate evil.
- Prov 8:13 – To fear the Lord is to hate evil.  I hate pride and arrogance.
- Prov 13:5 – The righteous hate what is false.
- Amos 5:14, 15 – Seek good, not evil, that you may live … hate evil, love good …
- Rom 13:14 – Rather, clothe yourselves with the Lord Jesus Christ and do not think about how to gratify the desires of the sinful nature.
- James 1:14, 15 – but each one is tempted when by his own evil desire, he is dragged away and enticed.  Then, after desire has conceived it gives birth to sin; and sin, when it is full grown, gives birth to death.

**CONCLUSION**

True faith/belief in Jesus as our Saviour is more than just mental ascent!  Faith in Christ is a transforming faith that changes the Christian for good so that others will notice that change.

Comment: Huh. I'd never noticed the 1-2-3-4-5-6 pattern before. I wonder if there's something to be interpreted in the Laodicean case from that.

Comment: Excellence. Much appreciated. (+1).

Answer (score 4):

Everyone who believes in Jesus Christ, but simultaneously does not fulfil His commandment that "Kingdom of Heaven is taken by violence" (Matthew 11:12), that is to say, by a fight with and victory over one's own sinfulness, and does not participate in His victory over the world (John 16:33) to which victory He called all His believers, for He called them also not to be of this world, i.e. vanquishers of this world (John 15:19), then such a one does not really believe in Jesus Christ but only purports to believe in Him, while in reality killing His salvific work in his heart.

Such a belief, thus, equals to unbelief and apostasy, for belief without acting according to this belief is a dead belief (James 2:26).

**Therefore**, 
yes, only those who overcome the world through the Overcomer's, i.e Christ's working in their hearts with their free co-working, will inherit the Kingdom of Heaven.

Answer (score 1):

OP writes:

> In Revelation 2:7 Jesus says:
>
> "He who has an ear, let him hear what the Spirit says to the churches.
>   To him who overcomes, I will grant to eat of the tree of life which is
>   in the Paradise of God."*emphasized text*
>
> Is this verse saying that only overcomers are allowed to eat of the
>   tree of life? What is the result of eating fruit from this tree, if
>   not eternal life (for those who say John 3:16 means that everyone who
>   believes in Christ obtains eternal life).

I've often wondered why so many think that 'just believing' is enough. There is nothing 'narrow' about the path of 'easy-believe-ism'.

Matt. 7:14 (KJV) - Because strait is the gate, and ***narrow*** is the way, which leadeth unto life, and few there be that find it.

The other day I began re-reading *The Nag Hammadi Library* by James M. Robinson.

In the Gospel of Philip:

> If one go down into the water and come up without having received
>   anything and says, "I am a Christian," he has borrowed the name at
>   interest. But if he receive the holy spirit, he has the name as a
>   gift. He who has received a gift does not have to give it back, but of
>   him who has borrowed it at interest, payment is demanded....

From other studies, I have become convinced that the object is to die and be transformed *while still in the flesh*. Like CS Lewis said, "Die before you die, there is no chance after."  The Holy Spirit is the Christ who must rise with us, bringing the dead to Life.

"Forgiveness is Divine. It comes from Within."

Answer (score 1):

**Question: "Is eternal life only for overcomers?**

In Revelation 2:7 Jesus says:

"He who has an ear, let him hear what the Spirit says to the churches. To him who overcomes, I will grant to eat of the tree of life which is in the Paradise of God."

"Is this verse saying that only overcomers are allowed to eat of the tree of life? What is the result of eating fruit from this tree, if not eternal life (for those who say John 3:16 means that everyone who believes in Christ obtains eternal life)."

**To answer, "Is eternal life only for overcomers?**

**The answer is YES!** We are in the Spiritual Battle!**

When you confess Jesus Christ is your Lord and Savior, you are in the spiritual battle, not a war because the war is WON by Christ. It is a battle against entities without flesh and blood. It is a real and organized even has schemes. The Bible says in Eph. 6:12:

“For we do not wrestle against flesh and blood, but against principalities, against powers, against the rulers of the darkness of this age, against spiritual hosts of wickedness in the heavenly places”

It is like a life-and-death, mortal hand-to-hand combat, engaged our whole person, body, soul and spirit.

They use same old scheme for the warfare, of which the Scripture has details as follow (not exhaustive):

**Enemy:** 
**Weapons:** Darts/arrows(metaphor)(Eph 6:16) of lies, deception, and doubts, 
          fears, seduction etc.

**Tactics**: Prowls around like a roaring lion looking for someone to devour.

**Uniform & disguis**e: Wolf in sheep skin (Mt. 7:15, Angel of light (2 Cor 
          11:14)- false  prophets, & messiah, pastor, christian, etc.

**Attack points: "the desire of the flesh and the desire of the eyes and the 
         arrogance** produced by material possessions" (1 John 2:16-NET)

**Armors for Christian**s: Belt of Truth; Breastplate of righteousness; shoe of 
         gospel peace; shield of faith; Helmet of salvation; sword of the Spirit 
         (the word of God); radio (metaphor) open communication with God in 
         prayer and supplication (Eph 6:14-18)

**Summary:** 
1. It's a real battle, and life and death (spiritually)
2. Heavenly help is assured -Holy Spirit & Heavenly hosts
3. Christians have roles to play and active participation essential.
4. Warnings: Apostasy, back-sliding
   (Mt. 10:32) -"Whoever, then, acknowledges me before people, I will acknowledge 
    before my Father in heaven.

(Heb. 6: 4-6)-"For it is impossible, in the case of those who have once been 
    enlightened, who have tasted the heavenly gift, and have shared in the Holy 
    Spirit, and have tasted the goodness of the word of God and the powers of the 
    age to come,and then have fallen away, to restore them again to repentance, 
    since they are crucifying once again the Son of God to their own harm and 
    holding him up to contempt."

2 Pet 2:20-22) - "For if, after they have escaped the defilement of the world 
     through the knowledge of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ, they are again 
     entangled in them and overcome, the last state has become worse for them 
     than the first. For it would have been better for them never to have known 
     the way of righteousness than after knowing it to turn back from the holy 
     commandment delivered to them. that the true proverb says has happened to 
     them: “The dog returns to its own vomit, and the sow, after washing herself, 
     returns to wallow in the mire.”

(Heb. 10:26-29) -"For if we go on sinning deliberately after receiving the 
     knowledge of the truth, there no longer remains a sacrifice for sins, 27but 
     a fearful expectation of judgment, and a fury of fire that will consume the 
     adversaries....."

**Notes**: There are more Scripture verses warning of the danger of falling. But also God assures us that He will receive back again and restore us when we return in repentance while Father waits (e.g. the prodigal son)

5. God's assurance for those who remain in Christ,
   (Rom 8: 35) -" Who shall separate us from the love of Christ? Shall 
   tribulation, or distress, or persecution, or famine, or nakedness, or danger, 
   or sword).

   (John 6: 40) - "For this is the will of my Father, that everyone who looks on 
   the Son and believes in him should have eternal life, and I will raise him up 
   on the last day.”
6. We all can win the battle and be overcomer! Keep eyes fixed upon and follow 
   our captain Jesus!

Answer (score 1):

**Is eternal life only for overcomers?**

The overcomers are the "partakers of the heavenly calling", (Heb.3:1) to them God promises to grand them immortality and incorruptibility in heaven (1 Cor. 15:53-54 KJV).To the other group which will be resurrected, (John 3:16) will be granted everlasting life on earth, provided they remain obedient according to the scrolls/books opened, Revelation 20:12. Probably to a life that Adam would have entertained if he did not sin.

**Partakers of the heavenly calling.**

Hebrews 3:1  (KJV)

> 3 "Wherefore, holy brethren, partakers of the heavenly calling,
>   consider the Apostle and High Priest of our profession, Christ Jesus;"

What is the result of eating fruit from this tree, if not eternal life (for those who say John 3:16 means that everyone who believes in Christ obtains eternal life).

The resurrected Jesus Christ promises the overcomers, that he will grant them to eat of the tree of life which is in the Paradise of God. ( Rev 2:6-7)The paradise of God is in heaven and is referring  to those overcomers that "will not be hurt by the second death." (Rev. 2:10-11)

**The result of eating fruit from this tree**

They will be given authority over the nations:

Revelation 2:26  (KJV)

> 26 And he that **overcometh**, and keepeth my works unto the end, to him
>   will I give power over the nations:

Who will be made a “pillar in the temple of My God”

Revelation 3:12  (NASB)

> 12 He who **overcomes,** I will make him a pillar in the temple of My God,
>   and he will not go out from it anymore; and I will write on him the
>   name of My God, and the name of the city of My God, the new Jerusalem,
>   which comes down out of heaven from My God, and My new name.

And who will sit down with Christ in his heavenly throne.

Revelation 3:21 (KJV)

> 21 To him that **overcometh** will I grant to sit with me in my throne,
>   even as I also overcame, and am set down with my Father in his throne.

And will rule with Jesus for a thousand years.

Revelation 20:4  (NASB)

> 4 "Then I saw thrones, and they sat on them, and judgment was given to
>   them. And I saw the souls of those who had been beheaded because of
>   [a]their testimony of Jesus and because of the word of God, and those
>   who had not worshiped the beast or his image, and had not received the
>   mark on their forehead and on their hand; and they came to life and
>   reigned with Christ for a thousand years."

What is the "second death" Revelation 20:14 explains:

Revelation 20:14 (NASB)

> 14 "Then **death** and **Hades** were thrown into the **lake of fire.** This is the
>   second death, the lake of fire."

**So what is the Lake of Fire?**

The Lake of Fire is symbolic, this is indicated by the fact that death and hades, two intangible things, that cannot be literally burned up, are thrown into it.Also, the fact that the Devil an invisible spirit creature is thrown into the lake is further proof that the lake is symbolic, spirit creatures cannot be hurt by literal fire. (Rev. 20:10, Judges 13:20.)  Hence the lake is a symbol, not of everlasting torment, but of everlasting destruction

Revelation 21:8  (NASB)

> But for the cowardly and [a]unbelieving and abominable and murderers
>   and immoral persons and sorcerers and idolaters and all liars, their
>   part will be in the lake that burns with fire and brimstone, which is
>   the second death.”

Two groups of individuals, benefit from God's love. The "Overcomers", Jesus referred to them as his "least brothers"  (Mat. 25:40 NASB) in the parable of the sheep and the goats.(Judgement Day, Mat.25:31-46) . The other group is the sheep which his places on his right side, a position of favor, referred to as the meek at Matthew 5:5, Jesus promises them that they will inherit the earth.

**The "Overcomers"**

He told his faithful disciples that he was about to prepare a place for them so that they might rule with him in heaven.

John 14:2-3 (KJV)

> 2 "In my Father's house are many mansions: if it were not so, I would
>   have told you. I go to prepare a place for you.  3 And if I go and
>   prepare a place for you, I will come again, and receive you unto
>   myself; that where I am, there ye may be also.

Jesus promised them everlasting, incorruptible, and immortal life in heaven.

Philippians 3:20-21  (NASB)

> 20 For our citizenship is in heaven, from which also we eagerly wait
>   for a Savior, the Lord Jesus Christ; 21 who will transform the body of
>   our humble state into conformity with [c]the body of His glory, by the
>   exertion of the power that He has even to subject all things to
>   Himself.

Romans 2:6-7  (NASB)

> 6 "Who will render to each person according to his deeds: 7 to those
>   who by perseverance in doing good seek for glory and honor and
>   immortality, eternal life;"

1 Peter 1:23  (NASB)

> 23 For you have been born again not of seed which is perishable but
>   imperishable, that is, through the living and enduring word of God.

Revelation 20:6 (KJV)

> 6 "Blessed and holy is he that hath part in the first resurrection: on
>   such the second death hath no power, but they shall be priests of God
>   and of Christ, and shall reign with him a thousand years."

Luke 12:32 (KJV)

> 32 Fear not, little flock; for it is your Father's good pleasure to
>   give you the kingdom.

As the name implies "little flock" their number is limited.(Rev. 14:1-4)

The other group is the faithful ones, that will look forward to everlasting life on earth, referred to as the sheep in the parable of the sheep and the goats (Vs 25:32 NET) In other words, those "sheep" look forward to everlasting life on earth​, the same prospect that Adam and Eve originally entertained.

Matthew 5:5,(KJV),

> The meek will inherit the earth.

Revelation 21:4 (KJV)

> 4 "And God shall wipe away all tears from their eyes; and there shall
>   be no more death, neither sorrow, nor crying, neither shall there be
>   any more pain: for the former things are passed away."

The wicked shall  be no more, but the meek shall  inherit the earth

Psalm 37:9-11 (KJV)

> 9 For evildoers shall be cut off: but those that wait upon the Lord,
>   they shall inherit the earth.10 For yet a little while, and the wicked
>   shall not be: yea, thou shalt diligently consider his place, and it
>   shall not be. 11 But the meek shall inherit the earth; and shall
>   delight themselves in the abundance of peace.

The righteous will flourish, an abundance of peace, an abundance of grain
.
Psalm 72:7-8, 16  (KJV)

7 "In his days shall the righteous flourish; and abundance of peace so long as the moon endureth. 8 He shall have dominion also from sea to sea, and from the river unto the ends of the earth. 16 May there be abundance of grain in the earth on top of the mountains;Its fruit will wave like the cedars of Lebanon;  And may those from the city flourish like vegetation of the earth.2

Isaiah 35:5-6  (KJV)

> 5 "Then the eyes of the blind shall be opened, and the ears of the
>   deaf shall be unstopped.6 Then shall the lame man leap as an hart, and
>   the tongue of the dumb sing: for in the wilderness shall waters break
>   out, and streams in the desert."

Isaiah 65:21-23  (KJV)

> 21 "And they shall build houses, and inhabit them; and they shall
>   plant vineyards, and eat the fruit of them.22 They shall not build,
>   and another inhabit; they shall not plant, and another eat: for as the
>   days of a tree are the days of my people, and mine elect shall long
>   enjoy the work of their hands. 23 They shall not labour in vain, nor
>   bring forth for trouble; for they are the seed of the blessed of the
>   Lord, and their offspring with them."

Answer (score 0):

Another way to say it may be "he or she who eats the tree of life, overcomes." I am the way and the reality and the life; no one comes to the Father except through Me. **Jn 14:6.** He who eats Me, he also shall live because of Me. **Jn 6:57.** The reward for eating the tree of life isn't something other than more tree of life, more Christ.

God so loved the world that He gave His only Son, that every one who believes into Him would not perish, but would have eternal life. **Jn 3:16.** When we first believed, our spirit permanently became life. If Christ is in you, though the body is dead because of sin, the spirit is life because of righteousness. **Rm 8:10.** The goal of the Christian life, the goal of God, is for our soul to become life. Another name for that is "growth." The mind set on the flesh is death, but the mind set on the spirit is life and peace...For if you live according to the flesh, you must die, but if by the Spirit you put to death the practices of the body, you will live. **Rm 8:6, 13.** The overcomers in Rv 2--3 are those who do this, experience this, soonest.

The finishing reward is when our bodies "become" life. For the anxious watching of the creation eagerly awaits the revelation of the sons of God...And not only so, but we ourselves also, who have the firstfruits of the Spirit, even we ourselves groan in ourselves, eagerly awaiting sonship, the redemption of our body...Because those whom He foreknew, He also predestinated to be conformed to the image of His Son, that He might be the Firstborn among many brothers; and those whom He predestinated, these He also called; and those whom He called, these He also justified; and those whom He justified, these He also glorified. **Rm 8:19, 23, 29-30.** We will not all sleep, but we will all be changed, in a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trumpet; for the trumpet will sound, and the dead will be raised incorruptible, and we will be changed. For this corruptible must put on incorruption, and this mortal must put on immortality. And when this corruptible will put on incorruption and this mortal will put on immortality, then the word which is written will come to pass, 'Death has been swallowed up unto victory.' **1 Cor 15:51-54.**

You're right: the result of eating the tree of life is more life

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

The short answer about the overcomers is "yes".

The long answer....

The Lord Jesus Christ comes to open up our minds by the opening up of the Scriptures to our understanding….the Word of Truth.   This is His “testimony”….the opening up of the Scriptures to our hearing ears in this last time.

It will not align or conform with what the word of man has been deceptively preaching for generations…. man’s various private interpretations of the Scriptures in order to deceive many and get paid for it.

One must overcome our own religious thoughts/understanding and ways for His thoughts/understanding and ways (which are higher than ours) when we hear the Word of Truth.

The hearers of His words….the hearing of what the Spirit is saying today to the churches…are to overcome those things that He points out.   We must hear the Spirit of Truth today and overcome.

Paul overcame his own religious thoughts and ways….counting all those things but a loss….in order to gain the excellency of the knowledge of Jesus Christ  the Lord…and we are to do the same today and not hold on to the thoughts and ways of our church “fathers”.   We are not to be found defending their “knowledge”  nor their ways…their handwriting of church dogmas…the doctrines and commandments of men.

> Philippians 3:6-10 KJV (6)  *Concerning zeal, persecuting the church;
>   touching the righteousness which is in the law, blameless. (7)  But
>   what things were gain to me, those I counted loss for Christ. (8)  **Yea
>   doubtless, and I count all things but loss for the excellency of the
>   knowledge of Christ Jesus my Lord: for whom I have suffered the loss
>   of all things, and do count them but dung, that I may win Christ,***

Paul was found in Christ instead of going about defending his own righteousness.

He instead believed in what he heard the Lord saying….the faith of Christ and the righteousness which is of God by that faith.   He didn’t argue with the Lord about what he heard but was found believing and overcoming his own religious thoughts and ways.   He was found in Christ by dying to sin (evil speaking)….being made conformable unto His death.

> (9)  ***And be found in him, not having mine own righteousness,*** which is
>   of the law, but that which is through the faith of Christ, **the
>   righteousness which is of God by faith: (10)  That I may know him,** and
>   the power of his resurrection, and the fellowship of his sufferings,
>   being made conformable unto his death;

This is eternal life….that we might know the only true God and Jesus Christ whom He sends.  We show we know Him by the doing of His commandments….especially at the moment we hear His voice as He is sent to give us an understanding so that we might turn to Him and live His eternal life now in this earth.

> John 17:2-3 KJV (2)  *As thou hast given him **power over all flesh, that
>   he should give eternal life** to as many as thou hast given him. (3) 
>   **And this is life eternal, that they might know thee the only true God,
>   and Jesus Christ, whom thou hast sent**.*

Again, the Son of God comes and gives us an understanding (by the opening up of the Scriptures to our minds through His interpretation of them).   We show that we know Him by the doing of His  commandments at the hearing of this heavenly “understanding” presented to us. We believe that this is His Son that we hear speaking in the Spirit of Truth (he that hears the voice of the Lord, let him hear in faith of what the Spirit is saying to the churches).

> 1 John 5:20 KJV (20)  *A**nd we know that the Son of God is come, and
>   hath given us an understanding, that we may know him that is true, and
>   we are in him that is true, even in his Son Jesus Christ. This is the
>   true God, and eternal life**.*

We show that we know God who is true by the keeping of His commandments.   We are to let brotherly love continue and entertain His words….without contentions, envy, strife, wrath, etc.

> 1 John 2:3-6 KJV (3)  ***And hereby we do know that we know him, if we
>   keep his commandments. (4)  He that saith, I know him, and keepeth not
>   his commandments, is a liar, and the truth is not in him.*** (5)  But
>   whoso keepeth his word, in him verily is the love of God perfected:
>   hereby know we that we are in him. (6)  **He that saith he abideth in
>   him ought himself also so to walk, even as he walked**.

We must overcome our own thoughts and ways in order to inherit all things.   He that overcomes shall inherit all things.

We are to affirm that these revealed words of the Lord are “true and faithful” when we hear them as we are then at His throne.  The Day arrives when we hear His words and we are to be found “awake” to the doing of His righteousness and not being forgetful to do His will....being bogged down in the worldly things.

We either receive His words and do good or reject them and do evil and are judged accordingly.

> Revelation 21:5-8 KJV (5)  *And he that sat upon the throne said,
>   Behold, I make all things new. And he said unto me, **Write: for these
>   words are true and faithful**.*

The true Jesus our Lord is the author and finisher of our faith.  He is the Beginning and the End….the completion of our faith.

We are to hear His voice and attest that His words are “true and faithful” and every man’s words that has been preached before were erroneous and are to be rejected…to be counted as a loss for the excellency of His knowledge.

Let God be true and every man a liar.  Whoever will receive the testimony of Jesus certifies that God is true while what man has been preaching is erroneous and disregarded.

We are to bring forth good deeds towards the hearing of His “true and faithful” words….sealing that God is true.

Faith with good deeds towards the hearing of His words of knowledge completes our faith…. “it is done” or finished.   Good works completes our faith.   He is the author…the beginning…and the completion of our faith as we hear His voice and do His commandments which completes faith in Him.

Only then (the completion of our faith through the keeping of His commandments) can we go into the full understanding of His knowledge:  “ I will give unto him that is thirsty of the fountain of the water of life freely.”  He will give His full knowledge unto those who will complete  or show the evidence of their faith in Him and His words by the good deeds towards Him and what they hear Him saying.

> (6)  **And he said unto me, It is done. I am Alpha and Omega, the
>   beginning and the end. I will give unto him that is athirst of the
>   fountain of the water of life freely.**

He that overcomes shall inherit all things and He will be our God and the overcomer shall be His son.

> (7)  **He that overcometh shall inherit all things; and I will be his
>   God, and he shall be my son.**

But those who will not overcome shall have their part in the lake which burns with fire and brimstone….which is the second death.  They will not go into His full understanding but will be left “outside” of His knowledge because of their evil deeds towards the hearing of His voice.   Without are those who will be found not doing His commandments at the hearing of His voice.

Some believers  of what they will hear will fear persecution from  other churchgoers for believing His words that are “true and faithful” and will hide their faith….not completing their faith.  What they thought they had…their faith… will be removed from them as judgment and have their part in the lake which burns with fire and brimstone.

Some churchgoers will not believe in what they will have heard at all.

Some will become angry towards what they hear:  His words that are “true and faithful”.  Some will “kill the messenger” (who will speak His words) with evil speaking…thereby, murdering their brother.

The liars say they know God but do not do His commandments.

Others will continue on as business as usual:  the handling of the Word of God deceptively for their own unjust gain.  They will not enter in to His knowledge.

> (8)  **But the fearful, and unbelieving, and the abominable, and
>   murderers, and whoremongers, and sorcerers, and idolaters, and all
>   liars, shall have their part in the lake which burneth with fire and
>   brimstone: which is the second death.**

The “second death” is the condition of being judged without mercy for the rejection of His true and faithful words. The tongue is a fire which will speak evil and will not cease as final judgment at the hearing of His words.

They will be “tormented” at His words and cannot receive them in faith as their judgment will be final upon them.   They will die from this earth in their sins…their evil speaking.

As Jesus said to the unbelievers, “you shall die in your sins” if they did not believe that He (I am) was who He said He is:   the Son of God who was speaking to them.  The judgment of unceasing speaking evil (sins) is final until one dies from this earth (the second death).

> John 8:23-24 KJV (23)  *And he said unto them, Ye are from beneath; I
>   am from above: ye are of this world; I am not of this world. (24)  **I
>   said therefore unto you, that ye shall die in your sins: for if ye
>   believe not that I am he, ye shall die in your sins.**

If we sin willfully…continuing to speak evil after we have received the knowledge of the Truth, there remains no more sacrifice for sins. Our judgment will then be final. What was once "willful" speaking evil will then become unwilful in the final, righteous judgment of God.  It will be unceasing evil speaking of the tongue which will bring ourselves torment.  The "worm"...the uncontrolled, unceasing blurting of evil....will not die.  The fire of the tongue shall not be quenched.

We shall have our part in the lake that burns with fire and brimstone as there is no remedy (the sacrifice of our Lord) for not doing His commandments at the hearing of His full knowledge as He shall open up the Scriptures to our hearing ears.  There will be no mercy shown as a result of continued speaking evil without the repenting of it.

> Hebrews 10:26-31 KJV (26)  ***For if we sin wilfully after that we have
>   received the knowledge of the truth, there remaineth no more sacrifice
>   for sins,*** (27)  But a certain fearful looking for of judgment and
>   fiery indignation, which shall devour the adversaries.

This judgment then will be “without mercy” and it will be final until we perish from off this earth in our sins….the unceasing of speaking evil.  The tongue is a fire which will bring us torment….rage and lamentation.   And there will then be no mercy….no sacrifice will be available.

> (28)  *He that despised Moses' law **died without mercy** under two or
>   three witnesses: (29)  Of how much sorer punishment, suppose ye, shall
>   he be thought worthy, who hath trodden under foot the Son of God, and
>   hath counted the blood of the covenant, wherewith he was sanctified,
>   an unholy thing, and hath done despite unto the Spirit of grace? (30) 
>   For we know him that hath said, Vengeance belongeth unto me, I will
>   recompense, saith the Lord. **And again, The Lord shall judge his
>   people. (31)  It is a fearful thing to fall into the hands of the
>   living God**.*

The drink of the wine of the wrath of God will be poured without mixture as His judgment will be made without mercy mixed in.

And those who will have done evil towards the hearing of His voice shall be “tormented” with fire (the tongue is a fire…a world of evil) and brimstone (the divine, righteous judgment of God continues upon them).

They will die in their sins….their continued, unwilful, unceasing evil speaking which is the final judgment upon them for their previous willful, continued speaking evil of what they heard.

They will be tormented in the presence of the “holy angels”…that is, the true and faithful words of the Lord spoken.  They will hear His words and rage upon what they hear…as it and their own words will torment them.   They will gnash their teeth in rage against His true and faithful words and will lament as their own evil will come back upon them.

They will be tormented in the presence of the Lamb….that is, in the presence of those who will keep the daily sacrifice of the Lord by the dying to sin.   They will not return evil for the evil of the persecutions of those who are being judged... who have their part in the lake that burns with fire and brimstone.

> Revelation 14:10-13 KJV (10)  ***The same shall drink of the wine of the
>   wrath of God, which is poured out without mixture into the cup of his
>   indignation; and he shall be tormented with fire and brimstone in the
>   presence of the holy angels, and in the presence of the Lamb***:

The smoke of their torment will ascend up "for ever and ever"….that is, there will be no more sacrifice for their sins as their judgment is final until they die for their sins….the “second death”. Forever = final judgment upon them without remedy of the sacrifice of the Lord to atone for their sins.  The only way out is for them to die from off this earth while in their sins ...the second death.

> (11)  And the smoke of their torment ascendeth up for ever and ever:
>   and they have no rest day nor night, who worship the beast and his
>   image, and whosoever receiveth the mark of his name. (12)  Here is the
>   patience of the saints: here are they that keep the commandments of
>   God, and the faith of Jesus.

But blessed those who are “dead” which “die” in the Lord…that is, those who will keep the dying of the Lord in their bodies.  They will die to sin…evil speaking…in the face of the persecutions of the group that is dying in their sins without remedy. They will inherit the eternal life of Jesus in this earth.  They will have peace while the other group will not.

> (13)  **And I heard a voice from heaven saying unto me, Write, Blessed
>   are the dead which die in the Lord from henceforth: Yea, saith the
>   Spirit, that they may rest from their labours; and their works do
>   follow them.**

Blessed are they that do His commandments so that they may have right upon the tree of life….and they will enter in to know His knowledge.

> Revelation 22:11-17 KJV (11)  He that is unjust, let him be unjust
>   still: and he which is filthy, let him be filthy still: and he that is
>   righteous, let him be righteous still: and he that is holy, let him be
>   holy still. (12)  And, behold, I come quickly; and my reward is with
>   me, to give every man according as his work shall be. (13)  I am Alpha
>   and Omega, the beginning and the end, the first and the last. (14) 
>   **Blessed are they that do his commandments, that they may have right to
>   the tree of life, and may enter in through the gates into the city.**

Outside in the darkness of not knowing His knowledge will be those who will hear His voice and will not overcome but will continue on.  The wicked shall  not have His understanding.

> (15)  **For without are dogs, and sorcerers, and whoremongers, and
>   murderers, and idolaters, and whosoever loveth and maketh a lie. (16) 
>   I Jesus have sent mine angel to testify unto you these things in the
>   churches. I am the root and the offspring of David, and the bright and
>   morning star. (17)  And the Spirit and the bride say, Come. And let
>   him that heareth say, Come. And let him that is athirst come. And
>   whosoever will, let him take the water of life freely**

.

Answer (score -1):

You people need to read Romans chapter 10 if you don’t think only believing and confessing that Jesus is Lord is enough to get you to heaven.

Comment: slightly of the topic was there such a thing as a Church at the time these things were written?

Comment: This answer is well below the standard of hermeneutical analysis and courtesy of response expected on this site. Please see the Tour and the Help as to the purpose and the functioning of SE-BH.